# How to concatenate Pandas dataframes built from multiple requests/JSON responses?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that I use to send a request to an endpoint and receive a JSON response that looks as follows:

```
{'SalesInfoStatus': {'next_offset': 15,
  'sales': [{'saSalesID': '761S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': '761',
    'origin': 'New York',
    'destination': 'London',
    'filed_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/19/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
     'actual_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/19/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
    'inbound_saSalesID': '761S-1666029229-adhoc-0:0'},
   {'saSalesID': '762S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': '762',
    'origin': 'New York',
    'destination': 'London',
    'filed_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/17/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
     'actual_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/17/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
    'inbound_saSalesID': '762S-1666029229-adhoc-0:0'},

   {'saSalesID': '765S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': '765',
    'origin': 'Paris',
    'destination': 'Tokyo',
    'filed_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/15/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
     'actual_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/15/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
    'inbound_saSalesID': '765S-1666029229-adhoc-0:0'},

   {'saSalesID': '767S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': '767',
    'origin': 'Los Angeles',
    'destination': 'Sydney',
    'filed_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/13/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
     'actual_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/13/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
    'inbound_saSalesID': '767S-1666029229-adhoc-0:0'}

]}}
```

I then build a Pandas dataframe from the response.

Here is the code:

```
identifier = ['S1234']

url = https://example.com/json/ident={identifier}

response = requests.get(url, auth=(user_name, api_key)).json()

try:
    df = pd.json_normalize(response['SalesInfoStatus']['sales'])[['actual_departure_time.date', 'origin', 'destination', 'ident']]

except KeyError:
     print('Identifier not found.')
```

I'd like to to iterate through a ***list of about a handful of identifiers***, build a Pandas dataframe ***for each***, then build one unified dataframe consisting of each of the individual dataframes (i.e. concatenate each dataframe to build only one Pandas dataframe).

Let's assume the list of identifiers is:

```
identifiers = ['S1234', 'S2345', 'S3456', 'S4567', 'S5678']
```

**The only wrinkle is that `['SalesInfoStatus']['sales']` could be empty.**

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Convert the entire structure to a data frame:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(response['SalesInfoStatus']['sales'])
```

Check if the structure is empty:

```
if df.empty:
    print('dataframe is empty')
```

If the structure is not empty, extract the relevant columns to create the unified data frame and create a list of individual data frames based on the identifier list:

```
else:
    df = df[['actual_time.date', 'origin', 'destination', 'identifier']]
    print(df)
    df_list = []
    identifiers = ['761', '765']
    for identifier in identifiers:
        df_list.append (df[df['identifier'] == identifier])
    for d in df_list:
        print(d)
```

`df` will be your unified data frame, `df_list` will contain the individual data frames for each identifier.

Note that the data field names slightly differ between your json example and your code (actual_time/actual_departure_time, identifier/ident).